# Pandas group by a specific value in any of given columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given the pandas dataframe as follows:

```
   Partner1 Partner2    Interactions
0  Ann      Alice       1
1  Alice    Kate        8
2  Kate     Tony        9
3  Tony     Ann         2
```

How can I group by a specific partner, let's say to find the total number of interactions of Ann?

Something like

```
gb = df.groupby(['Partner1'] or ['Partner2']).agg({'Interactions': 'sum'})
```

and getting the answer:

```
Partner Interactions
Ann     3
Alice   9
Kate    17
Tony    11
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) together with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). First `melt`:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Interactions', value_vars=['Partner1', 'Partner2'], value_name='Partner')
```

This will give:

```
   Interactions   variable  Partner
0             1   Partner1      Ann
1             8   Partner1    Alice
2             9   Partner1     Kate
3             2   Partner1     Tony
4             1   Partner2    Alice
5             8   Partner2     Kate
6             9   Partner2     Tony
7             2   Partner2      Ann
```

Now, group by `Partner` and sum:

```
df.groupby('Partner')[['Interactions']].sum()
```

Result:

```
Partner  Interactions
  Alice             9
    Ann             3
   Kate            17
   Tony            11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do merge dataframe itself:

```
# join the df to itself
join_df = df.merge(df, left_on='Partner1', right_on='Partner2', suffixes=('', '_'))

# get sum
join_df['InteractionsSum'] = join_df[['Interactions', 'Interactions_']].agg(sum, 1)

join_df = join_df[['Partner1', 'Interactions']].copy()

print(join_df)

  Partner1  Interactions
0      Ann             1
1    Alice             8
2     Kate             9
3     Tony             2
```

Comment: Good solution, however in the end it would be:
print(join_df[['Partner1', 'InteractionsSum']])

Comment: well, you just need to select columns, check the edit